# Change an attribute of iframe that cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe, instagram-api

I have a instagram video embedded by iframe tag in wordpress website. I try to change one attribute of this video that is nested within the iframe. Look like this:

```
<iframe src="instagram.com/sth/sth">
  <#document>
   <html>
    <head>
    <body>
      <div1 class = "Embed">
        <div2 class = "Embed-video">

.......
</iframe>
```

If I want to change the class name of div2, how should I work around the cross domain issue? So far I have tried to reset the domain of subdomain, jquery plugin I found online,etc, nothing works.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: For security reasons, that is completely impossible.

Comment: You would need the source video uploaded on the server you want to display the content and embed using your own source if you want to manipulate the classes. Alternatively, you could embed directly using the source for the video and use your own javascript to format the embedding. You would embed using object tags

Comment: thank you @SteveKline. Could you give me some more information on object tags?